# How can I get six Xbox controllers to provide input to an HTML5 game?

Tags: html5, input, xbox-controller

I'm creating a six player HTML 5 game designed to be played locally ([Red Ice](http://pixieengine.com/projects/166/fullscreen)).

I've previous set up handling 7 Wiimotes using something along the lines of Joy2Key to map each input for each player to a separate keyboard key, but Wiimotes are pretty hard on the hands for these types of games and not very ergonomic so I thought I'd try and get Xbox controller support.

I don't believe that any simple key mapping solution will work due to the nature of the directional stick.

My inclination is that this will require a browser plugin and if so I'd prefer to write the plugin for Google Chrome.

How do I create a Chrome browser plugin to handle multiple Xbox controllers or is there some other way?

Please do not answer this question saying it can't be done, because it absolutely can.

EDIT: I don't believe any keymapping/mouse simulating solution will work unless it can reliably distinguish six axis of inputs, one per player.

Comment: Running on Windows?

Comment: Not enough blood :)

Comment: Have you tried something like [Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/)?

Comment: The standard library for using 360 controllers on Windows is XInput - http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/xinput.html however it only supports 4 controllers...

Comment: It should run on all major platforms (Linux, OSX, Windows) and browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE8+)

Comment: Relevant issue on Chrome for the Gamepad API: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=146285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created [Boomstick](https://github.com/STRd6/Boomstick), an NPAPI and ActiveX plugin that grants JavaScript an API to access native Joysticks and Gamepads. Assuming that 2 XBox 360 Wireless Gaming Receivers can each handle 4 controllers, Boomstick will grant HTML5 access to the 8 controllers. This works on all major platforms (Windows, Mac, and Linux) and browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your controllers are wireless, the first thing you'll need is the [Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2). It's a $20 USB device that lets you use your Xbox 360 controllers as input devices.

- If you're using **Mac OS X**, grab the [Tattibogle OS X controller driver](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver).
- On **Linux**, try the [xboxdrv userspace driver](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/).
- If you're using **Windows** there are probably thousands of options, but try starting with the [Pinnacle Game Profiler](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/) (as mentioned in the Amazon reviews for the dongle).

Once all that's set up it's a matter of syncing the controllers with the dongle and binding the buttons and sticks of each controller to different keypresses.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there such a thing as binding to a virtual keypress? (In a hypothetical extreme situation where all of the keyboard is already being used for another player's controls.)

Comment: These seem to be very close, but I still need the final step of giving JavaScript access to the actual axis input. Due to having six players I don't believe that I can just map the axes to the mouse coordinates.

Comment: Also, the receiver only handles up to 4 controllers...